# Linkedin Embeded post height to be without scroll dynamic

Tags: jquery, css

In LinkedIn embedded posts on my page each post has different height and it has scrolls. Is there any way i can make the height dynamic according to the post height?

```
<iframe src="https://www.linkedin.com/embed/feed/update/urn:li:share:6917261457768280064" height="950" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" title="Embedded post"></iframe>
```

https://codepen.io/salman-aziz/pen/XWVYbga

Comment: `height: auto;` the element will automatically adjust its height to allow its content to be displayed correctly

Comment: does not work like that. Check the codepen i have put code there.

Comment: when you copy the iframe code from Linkedin the height is already included as attribute.

Comment: @stan: yes i tried the post with provided height as an attribute by linkedin in some posts it does not give scroll but in some like example codepen it still has scroll i tried it with the provided attribute height by linkedin

Comment: I have resolved it with a trick of using an overlay and added a min height. To make post clickable i used a jQuery function. Its working.
Please review it here: https://codepen.io/salman-aziz/pen/XWVYbga

Comment: You can post this as an answer maybe it will help other people.

Comment: I have posted my answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. It has also helped me

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Get url from Iframe SRC add it in Anchor HREF
    function shareIframeUrl() {
        var src = $(".linkedinWidget iframe").attr('src');
        href = src.replace('embed/', '');
        $('#iframeurl').attr('href', href);
    }
    shareIframeUrl();
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
.linkedinWidget {
    position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.iframeurl {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 111;
}
.linkedinPosts {
    position: relative;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1606px;
}
.linkedinPosts:before {
    content: '';
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1em #fff;
}
.linkedinPosts iframe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1600px;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="linkedinWidget">
<a id="iframeurl" target="_blank" class="iframeurl" href="#"></a>
<div class="linkedinPosts">
<iframe src="https://www.linkedin.com/embed/feed/update/urn:li:share:6917261457768280064" height="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" title="Embedded post"></iframe></div></div>
```